# How to run setup scripts(InstallSchema/UpgradeSchema/InstallData/UpgradeData) without setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Is there any way to run Magento 2 setup scripts without `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: you can create your own command that does it, but what's the point? Maybe you should describe the problem you have

Comment: What you intend to achieve and why not to try upgrade command?

Comment: @Marius @Jai, I know we can use upgrade to run our setup scripts, I just want to know is there a way to run externally. If we run `setup:upgrade` , again we may have to do `di:compile` or `content:deploy` in order to get site up.

Comment: I still didnt get why you need to do this? Do you want a single command to execute all ?

Comment: No, I want to run particular setup script file externally.

Answer (score 3):

Look at file: `vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php`

In `execute` method, you can find all functions, which are firing on `setup:upgrade`.

Part you want is:

```
$installer->installSchema();
$installer->installDataFixtures();
```